# What would have happened if Hitler had launched operation Sea lion (the planned invasion of England in September 1940)?

Tags: science-based, warfare, alternate-history, military-defense, invasion

I'm writing a story set in an alternative history world but after some research I suspect the scenario I intend to use is unrealistic, so I would like to understand the likely outcome of Hitler’s operation Sea lion had it been launched. I am particularly interested in evidence based answers with reasoned explanations based on historic fact.

Assume that the air war against the RAF Fighter Command had remained focused on the airbases rather than being diverting to attack London, leaving fighter command further weakened.

Despite Hitler's reservations, assume that some other political event or serious public loss of face forced Hitler’s hand and he launched it anyway in a fit of rage.

Comment: Curious why the down vote?

Comment: In accordance with [community discussion](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3033/6986), voting to close as _too broad_.

Comment: The novel [SS-GB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-GB) might provide some insight.

Comment: As in, for real, I have never read any alternate history novel where the Germans get a moment of clear thinking and decide to do over with the English nuisance before opening a second front. No, I've never heard of *SS-GB*, *[Dominion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15770927-dominion)*, the *[Small Change](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42439-small-change)* series, *[Resistance](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/945882.Resistance)*...

Comment: The answer is British naval superiority. An article published in *History Today* analysed the difference in naval capacity and decided the vessels the Germans needed to use to invade Britain. Mainly, river barges (vide @PhilipRowlands' answer) could be sunk by Royal Navy ships just sailing by them. There are several books (nonfiction) that examined Operation Sea Lion. The consensus is it would fail decisively. One part of the air campaign the Germans targeted the radar aerials, but failed to maintain this. Had they done so, this could have turned the tide on the Battle of Britain. [continues]

Comment: [continued]: It is considered that the Battle of Britain & its success against the Germain assault was used a propaganda victory. This has tended to obscure the fact of British naval superiority as the main factor in stopping Operation Sea Lion from happening. However, it has left open the fallacious possibility that a German invasion of the UK might have succeeded. When, in fact. it was a complete non-starter.

Answer (score 2):

There was [a wargame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Sea_Lion_(wargame)) in the mid 70s which reenacted it, based on the known plans from both sides, and concluded that it would have failed. One of the assumptions was that the Luftwaffe would continue attacking air bases instead of cities, much like your scenario.

Other points in Britain's favour:

- [They were prepared to resort to chemical warfare if the Germans invaded.](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/sixty-secret-mustard-gas-sites-uncovered-1335343.html)
- Germany had almost no landing craft, apart from re-purposed river barges. These aren't exactly ships for raiding across the English Channel.
- The German military heavily relied on horses for logistics. Horses panic a *lot* more easily than a truck.
- The Germans had few, if any, spies in Britain - all of them were caught and turned into double agents.

Comment: *"Horses?"* Of all the reasons I've heard about WWII, I don't think I've ever heard about German war horses...

Comment: @Xen2050 precisely because their main purpose was transporting supplies and field artillery - which isn't as "exciting" as tank-vs-tank battles, D-Day, etc...

Comment: @Xen2050 Throughout the war, but especialy in the early years, horses were extensively used in transportation. The German armies initial plans called for more than 100,000 horses to be transported to England.